# How to implement boolean masking on TPU

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tpu

I need to implement a boolean masking operation using TPUEstimator. tf.boolean_mask is not implemented. Is there a workaround?

The following code works perfectly for my purpose on a CPU and GPU:

```
  all_out = model.get_sequence_output()
  P = tf.boolean_mask(all_out, P_mask)
```

all_out is a tensor of shape [?, 128, 768]

P_mask is shape [?, 128] and the second dimension is one-hot encoded to represent the desired tensor to extract.

The desired shape of P is [?,768]

When I run this on a TPU using TPUEstimator, I get the following error message:

```
Compilation failure: Detected unsupported operations when trying to
compile graph _functionalize_body_1[] on XLA_TPU_JIT: Where (No 
registered 'Where' OpKernel for XLA_TPU_JIT devices compatible with node
node boolean_mask/Where
```

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tensorflow-ops) on `tf.where` (which is called by `tf.boolean_mask` on TPU, see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/issues/236) too.

```
    tf.where    Both x and y must be non-None. If both x and y are None, the operator would not have a static shape.
```

The root reason is that you will not get static shape by doing these, thus as of today, tpu is not happy with that.

If your only purpose is to finally calculate a loss or sum, it is probably doable to rewrite your code.

```
Rewrite this:
   reduce_sum(gather_nd(tf.where(cond),Y))
to this:
   reduce_sum(Y * tf.cast(cond))
```

However, if you do need the dynamic shape of the masked output `[?, 768]`, I have no idea.

Comment: Thank you. I did find a more intricate workaround, but this is simpler and works well.

Comment: Hi Ken, if this answer solves your problem, would you mind accepting it (which would help the community)?